# Tabulator's "Min Max Custom Header Filter" reverts the filtering if initiated by a key press

Tags: filter, keypress, tabulator

The Custom Header filter for the Min Max filters the table and then reverts it back to its initial state before the filter was applied. This occurs when a key is pressed after a number is entered into both the min and max input boxes.

You can reproduce the error from this link [Min Max custom Header Filter from the documentation](http://tabulator.info/examples/4.5?#filter-header)

Reproducing Steps

1. go to http://tabulator.info/examples/4.5#filter-header
2. Navigate your mouse to the Progress column
3. Type the number 1 into the min area and 10 into the max area (make sure to fill out both before proceeding)
4. When finished hit the enter key

Expected behavior
The table filters only displaying the rows that satisfy the filter

Actual behavior
The table will show the rows that satisfy the filter but then it immediately reverts to the initial table before that filter was applied.

Clicking anywhere out of the input area fixes the filter. The problem is why does it behave this way for the keypresses.

I found this link [Link from a similar issue with key press and the custom header filter](https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/2409)

Oli's solution listed in the ticket was to edit the function for a keypress to make the "custom header filter" filter in real-time. However, this solution does not fix the issue with the keypress.

So far I have been tinkering with the function that handles the keypress with little success in fixing this issue.

I also tried the solution from the person who wrote the ticket in the link above. This did not work because applying those modifications prevented the keypress from initiating the filtering.

So, in summary, is there a way to modify the code so that any keypress filters the table and keeps it's filtered rows?

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue in the documentation example, it has been resolved in the [4.6 Example](http://tabulator.info/examples/4.6#filter-header)